# Get the average processing speed in YOLO

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, yolo, yolov5, yolov8

When using `Yolo` (v5 or v8) to process a video, it shows the detection speed per frame, like below (e.g. 80.6 ms). Now, is there a flag to get the average speed across all frames?

```
video 1/1 (563/570) /home/human/yolov5/video.mp4: 384x640 1 human, 80.6ms
video 1/1 (564/570) /home/human/yolov5/video.mp4: 384x640 1 human, 87.1ms
video 1/1 (565/570) /home/human/yolov5/video.mp4: 384x640 1 human, 89.8ms
video 1/1 (566/570) /home/human/yolov5/video.mp4: 384x640 1 human, 81.2ms
video 1/1 (567/570) /home/human/yolov5/video.mp4: 384x640 1 human, 75.5ms
video 1/1 (568/570) /home/human/yolov5/video.mp4: 384x640 1 human, 92.5ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Ultralytics library, you are getting the average speed per image at the end of the inference ('speed' in the output):

```
video 1/1 (177/178) /VID.mp4: 640x384 1 person, 1 sports ball, 631.5ms
video 1/1 (178/178) /VID.mp4: 640x384 1 person, 1 sports ball, 345.2ms
Speed: 4.2ms preprocess, 413.7ms inference, 1.6ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 384)
```

Also, speed information is available as the results attribute:

```
results = model('VID.mp4')
results[0].speed
# speed (dict): A dictionary of preprocess, inference, and postprocess speeds in milliseconds per image.
```